# How to retrieve all the column values(distinct had been applied) into listbox by using sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

This might be simple one and also this has been answered before but I don't know how to look for the exact method.

-> Am having two list box in my form. One is for product name and other one is for Company name.

-> On page load, `Listbox1` will retrieve values from `database(Product name)`. Once item has been selected from `listbox1`, the respective company names should be fetched in `listbox2`.

**For eg** : Database name is Motor

Here is my table named as "Register" and it contains two columns they are,

```
Productname        Companyname

Car                 Bmw
Bike                Bmw
Car                 Honda
Bike                Honda
```

**My Question is**

I retrieved product name details into `listbox1`, here the thing is i don't want to repeat the same items, so I used Distinct like this,

```
Select Distinct Productname from Register
```

**Now if i select car from listbox 1 then the respective company names should be display in listbox2. But what am getting is only Honda on my listbox2 and am not getting BMW.**

```
Sqlcommand cmd=new Sqlcommand("Select Companyname from Register where Productname='"+listbox1.selecteditem+"'",con);
Sqldatareader dr=cmd.Executereader();
while(dr.Read())
{
   string a=dr.GetString(0);
   listbox2.items.add(a);
}
```

This is the query which is used to retrieve values into listbox2. I used datareader to read and get the values from the database.

I don't know exactly how to do this. Hope am not confusing you.So any help would be more helpful to me and thanks in advance.

Comment: simply debugg your code and see what you query contains, and get the query and execute in sql server.

Comment: "I used datareader to read and get the values from the database." Post your code for reading the query resultset and binding it to your ListBox2

Comment: @ChrisL I have updated my question with query which i used.

Comment: From your query - you're not passing the string `a` to your Add(), however as you say you're only getting Honda, then i assume this is copy/paste error. I would suggest running your queries directly in the db and checking they return as expected.

Comment: Yeah that was a typing mistake. And as per your suggestion, i tried in db directly with my query, it gets executed. Am getting both BMW and Honda.But am not getting in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with,

```
    Select Companyname from Register 
    where Productname='"+listbox1.GetItemText(listbox1.SelectedItem)+"'
```

Comment: I have tried your way, but still no improvement. Am getting only the last stored value.

Comment: Have you checked that your query returns desired output in SQL Server?

Comment: I don't need in SQL Server. Check out my updated question. I just want to retrieve the values into listbox.

Comment: Can you please share your table structure? (Table1 from where you are fetching the ProductName and table2 i.e, table Register).

Comment: I have only one table with two columns. First Column is Productname and Second one is Companyname. Just have a look again on my question, you may understand what i tried and what am asking..!

Comment: You can use SqlDataAdapter instead of Sqldatareader, try this: 

`DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.open()
string cmdstr = 'Select Companyname from Register 
                 where Productname
                 ='"+listbox1.GetItemText(listbox1.SelectedItem)+"';

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conn);
adp.Fill(ds);
listbox2.DataSource = ds;
listbox2.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
listbox2.DataValueField = "ID";
listbox2.DataBind(); 
conn.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Sqlcommand cmd=new Sqlcommand("Select Companyname from Register where Productname='"+listbox1.selecteditem.toString()+"'",con);
Sqldatareader dr=cmd.Executereader();

listbox2.items.clear();

while(dr.Read())
{
   string a=dr['Companyname'].toString();
   listbox2.items.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ur using
string a=dr.GetString(0);
   listbox2.items.add(a);

which will fetch only first row from table..

use
string a=dr["companyname"].toString();
listbox2.items.add(a);

this should solve your problem.